# Renewing Intranet Site's Self-Signed Security Certificate

Tags: linux, web, debian, security

We have an intranet site that recently started displaying 'There is a problem with this website's security certificate' errors when users connect to it.  The website is running off of a Debian server.  How would I go about renewing the self-signed security certificate using the command line?  Thanks!

Comment: First of all, what's wrong with the certificate?  Visit the site in a browser and view the certificate information.  Give us the exact error message please.  Did it simply expire?  Does it work for some people but not others?  Is it browser or operating system specific?

Comment: If this is just a self signed certificate, I'd just generate another one.  You can find instructions here: http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#cert-self .  I'd recommend using -days 1826 (5 years) instead of -days 365 because if you only use one year, you'll end up going through this again before you know it.    I'd also use 2048 bit rsa instead of 1024, as well as the -sha512 option, to make sure it remains cryptographically viable for the whole duration.

Comment: @Wug Should convert that last comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the company that we got our previous certificate from and renewed our expired certificate.  They had instructions on how to install the newly generated script

Answer (score 0):

> How would I go about renewing the self-signed security certificate using the command line?

If this is just a self signed certificate, I'd just generate another one. You can find instructions [here.](http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#cert-self)

A brief excerpt:

> This example will produce a file called mycert.pem which will contain both the private key and the public certificate based on it. The certificate will be valid for 365 days, and the key (thanks to the -nodes option) is unencrypted.
>
> openssl req \
>     -x509 -nodes -days 365 \
>     -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem

I'd recommend using -days 1826 (5 years) instead of -days 365 because if you only use one year, you'll end up going through this again before you know it. I'd also use `rsa:2048` instead of `rsa:1024`, as well as the `-sha512` option, which should ensure your certificate remains cryptographically viable for the whole duration.

Also, to avoid the prospect of accidentally mixing your private key into the cert and forgetting about it, I'd use `-out mycert.crt`, which will store the certificate in a seperate file.